# data from kinect,rgb and depth images

Tags: ros, openni, depth-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,I installed Diamondback on Ubuntu 10.10,and the kinect openNI package,the problem I have so far is that I dont get any data from the kinect,neither rgb nor depth image!!
please if you know antything about how to fix that,let me know.
thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11743/data-from-kinect,rgb-and-depth-images/) by [bassim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1280/bassim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@bassim you have already asked this question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/2641/kinect-rospackage

please follow the guidelines at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0